# Jquery load multiple alerts

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am trying to bring the identification data from the HTML DOM with Jquery but when I press the button the first time, this is done twice, then it increases to 3 and so on ... I read that it is because Jquery I am getting all the data-identification, but he tried several things and none has given me the result.

```
 <script>
    function hi(text){
       $(document).ready(function() {
       $('button').on('click', function() {
       console.log(this.dataset.id, $(this).data().id, 
       $(this).data('id'));

       alert("It is done many times ...");
  });
});    
       }
    </script>
```

And php:

```
       $i = 0;

        foreach($arr as $data ){

        $iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new 
RecursiveArrayIterator($data), RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);
          $find_variables = (iterator_to_array($iterator,true));


          foreach($find_variables as $rec){
            if (is_array($rec)) {
              if (!empty($rec) && ($rec['text'] != '') ) {
              $manjar = json_encode($rec);
              $manj1 = htmlspecialchars($manjar , ENT_QUOTES);

                echo '</a></td><div id="my-div3"><td><button class="btn btn-danger" type="button" data-id="'.$i .'" onclick= "hi(' . $manj1 . ')">Info</a></td></tr>';

                $i++;   
              }else{
                continue;

              }

            }
          }


    }
```

In summary: I press click the first time and I get two alerts, I close it and press again on the button and three come out. I close them, I press the button again and four ... so on ... I would appreciate your help, I've been reviewing but nothing that works ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using two event listeners ... one is the inline `onclick` and inside the function `hi()` you add another event listener with jQuery.

Each time `hi()` is called in the `onclick` you add another listener again

Get rid of the inline `onclick` and get rid of the function `hi()` and just use the jQuery `on('click'..`

Use another data attribute to pass in `$manj1`

Comment: Is incredible. This worked. I thank you very much ... so I was redoing the events? Many thanks!